# error while importing data to postgres with java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

well my problem is that i need to import data to a postgres table through java from a csv file, the thing is when i import the data with PGadmin4 it is imported without errors, however when i
execute this sql statement with java `COPY account FROM 'path/account.csv' DELIMITER ','  QUOTE '"' HEADER CSV`  an exception occures stating this :
**was aborted: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "24/3/1995"
Indice : Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.**
i have checked the datetime and it's **dmy**

Comment: ooops my bad i was worng i just checked again, when i run the command show datestyle it returns ISO,DMY

Comment: @nissow: you need to check the `datestyle` setting for the session (and possibly user) from within your Java application. That might be different to the one you see in pgAdmin

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if i understand you right i have to execute the command show datestyle from my java application ?

Comment: Or just run `set datestyle = ` to set the correct format before running the copy command